# Accessing fields_for object in Rails undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fields-for

I'm trying to access my fields_for object in order to access its properties with no luck:

```
  <%= f.fields_for :items do |item| %>
    <%= item.object.id %>
  <% end %>
```

**Output:**

```
undefined local variable or method `item' for #<#<Class:0x0000000106aa5eb8>:0x000000012d4d6038>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feels like you are missing the instance here?

```rb
[...]
<%= f.fields_for :items, @some_instance.items do |item| %>
[...]
```

at least thats what a glance at the [docs](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for) might suggest